# Google Place Autocomplete not showing in Bootstrap modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal, google-maps-api-2

FIX UPDATE:
It seems that the way i was initializing the box was causing issues
here is what fixed it

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        var input = document.getElementById("keyword");
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        $('#my-modal').modal('show');

    });

</script>
<style>
    .pac-container {
        z-index: 10000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

UPDATE: I have updated the code to be very simple, the reason this http://jsfiddle.net/g8vxmLn9/1/  works is because its using older bootstrap and jquery so I assume because I am using newer i am having the problems.

I simply just want to show a autocomplete box in a bootstrap(3.3) model and have it show the results as you type.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Test</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places">   </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="my-modal" class="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <input name="keyword" id="keyword" type="text" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#my-modal").modal({
            show: false
        }).on("shown", function () {
            var input = document.getElementById("keyword");
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        });
        $('#my-modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id="map_canvas"` is not defined in JS

Comment: @Shehary I updated the code so that its simpler and has nothing to do with canvas, still doesnt work

Answer (score 75):

This fixed it

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var input = document.getElementById("keyword");
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        $('#my-modal').modal('show');

    });

</script>
<style>
    .pac-container {
        z-index: 10000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: <style>
    .pac-container {
        z-index: 10000 !important;
    }
</style> This works for me

Comment: _Explanation_: `.pac-container` is the wrapping div element of the Google Autocomplete result. In this case modal already has a high `z-index`. So you have to set higher `z-index` than the modal

Answer (score 27):

Just add

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are still looking.

```
                    var pacContainerInitialized = false; 
                    $('#inputField').keypress(function() { 
                            if (!pacContainerInitialized) { 
                                    $('.pac-container').css('z-index', '9999'); 
                                    pacContainerInitialized = true; 
                            } 
                    });
```

Answer (score 5):

For use with Angular 2+, make sure to use ng-deep

```
  ::ng-deep .pac-container
  {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the z-index of your modal, your .pac-container will need to be at least 1 higher.

Your stylesheet should include

```
.pac-container {z-index: 99999999999 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace inicialize function on load windows or, document ready, etc.
Solution: into box address input add onclick="initialize()".
It´s fine!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).